# Controller methods that are only called by AJAX, make private?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have methods on my controllers like `forgot_password`, `login` etc.

These are only called via AJAX but by default you can browse to them via URL due to the way CI works.

Can I somehow make them private and still access them via AJAX? What's the done thing here?

Comment: Accept the answer, if you feel that any of them is right! As others relay on your choice of answer.

Answer (score 17):

The best practice here is to use `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`

```
if(! $this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    redirect('404');
}
```

Comment: `show_404();` instead of `redirect('404');`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to test for ajax request, something like this may help.

**EDIT : There is a helper function in CI to detect ajax request .**
The answer is outdated

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest") 
{
// most probably ajax request
}
else
{
   echo "not sure";     
}
```